# Do I have to pass all handlebars data at once, or can these come from multiple different place?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to organize my code and can't figure out how (or if at all) I can feed my handlebars values from multiple files.

I'm currently setting up a website by utilizing `express` and `express-handlebars`. The `header` and `navigation bar` are partials, while the content will be using the `{{{body}}}` tag. Now when navigating to a specific page, let it be '/' for now, I will eventually end up calling:

```
res.render('index', {
    title: "Home"
});
```

Here I pass `title` over to the `layout.hbs` which places the `index.hbs` file into the `{{{body}}}` tag. `title` is used in the header partial. That's all good and the title is most likely changing depending on the what is rendered for the content `{{{body}}}` area. However I also have data that is always the same, such as user data which is located in my `navigation bar` (username and avatar at the top of it). I would now always need to pass both, username and avatar, to the `res.render(..)` call. Is that normal or can I split this somehow?

The actual `res.render` call looks like this atm:

```
router.get('/', catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {  
    if(req.authenticated) {
        res.render('index', {
            title: "Home",
            authenticated: true,
            username: req.userdetails.username,
            userid: req.userdetails.id,
            avatarid: req.userdetails.avatar
        });
    }
    else {
        // Render index view
        res.render('index', { 
            title: "Home",
            authenticated: false
        });
    }
}));
```

The `req.authenticated` and `req.userdetails` data comes from a middleware that I placed infront of my routes, so that I can make sure that the user is properly authenticated before showing important data (might not be the best solution, but it works for now and is not topic of this question).

Now the whole setup uses a `layout.hbs` which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- General Settings -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Some Title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Some Description.">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <!-- Material Design Light -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.blue_grey-deep_orange.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="demo-layout mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer mdl-layout--fixed-header">
            {{> header }}
            {{> navigation }}
            <!-- Content -->
            <main class="mdl-layout__content">
                {{{ body }}}
            </main>
        </div>
        <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Calling `res.render` will always pass through this `layout.hbs` and `{{> navigation}}` requires the username and avatar to be passed. I would love this data to come from somewhere else. Because otherwise I will eventually end up passing 20 variables to that specific render call, just because I also need to pass over everything from the navigation bar and header.

Isn't it possible to have another javascript file that calls something similar as `res.render` but only targeted at the {{> navigation}} partial?

In the end I would love to end up with something like this:

Content page only gets title:

```
router.get('/', catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {  
    if(req.authenticated) {
        res.render('index', {
            title: "Home",
            authenticated: true
        });
    }
    else {
        // Render index view
        res.render('index', { 
            title: "Home",
            authenticated: false
        });
    }
}));
```

While the navigation bar from somewhere else only gets the username stuff:

```
res.render('{{> navigation}}', {
    authenticated: true,
    username: req.userdetails.username,
    userid: req.userdetails.id,
    avatarid: req.userdetails.avatar
});
```

Or maybe the partial can pull data from a specific context?

Thanks for your time!